# Neo4j: How to return a single path for each pair of nodes that have multiple relationships

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, shortest-path, neo4j-apoc

Assuming a graph like this:

*(Thanks to https://neo4j.com/blog/neo4j-2-0-ga-graphs-for-everyone/ )*

[image]

*(Not shown but assume all countries, all artists, and all recording contracts are in the graph)*

What would the CYPHER be for:

- Starting with United Kingdom, return one path for each country where there is at least one recording contract

  - It doesn't matter *which* path is returned, just that it's a single path
  - *Should return `(United Kingdom)<-[]-(Iron Maiden)-[]->(Epic)-[]->(United States)`, but not `(United Kingdom)<-[]-(Hybrid Theory)-[]->(Mad Decent)-[]->(United States)` or `(United Kingdom)<-[]-(Iron Maiden)-[]->(Columbia)-[]->(United States)`, for example*
- Return a single path for each of *any* two countries that are connected

  - Should return one path for `(United Kingdom)-[]-(United States)`, one for `(Japan)-[]-(Canada)`, etc. *Bonus points for `LIMIT 20` limiting it to either 20 paths or 20 country nodes*
  - Also does not matter *which* path is returned, just that it's a single path

Edit: I've tried various combinations of `MATCH (c1:Country)-[]-(c2:Country)`, `MATCH p=((c1:Country)-[]-(c2:Country))`, `WITH`, and `UNWIND`. I've also tried to use `FOREACH` to return only one path, but can't quite get the formula right.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please show us your query and tell us what is the problem with it?  Addtional question: 1) What is the difference of UK->IronMaiden->Epic->US and UK->IronMaiden->Columbia->US? Why do you want the former?  2) Is this a project or homework in school?

Comment: I've added some notes about what I've tried so far. The full notes would be multiple pages so I'm trying to avoid overloading the question. 1) is an excellent question, and I'm sorry I didn't clarify: For the purposes it doesn't matter which of the paths are returned, just that only 1 path is returned for each pair. 2) It's a data-exploration project that might turn in to a production tool.

Comment: For the pairs returned, is it okay that a country can appear multiple times, as long as it's associated with a different pair? For example, if we have a path for `(United Kingdom)-[*]-(United States)`, it's okay to have a path for `(United Kingdom)-[*]-(Japan)` too, since the pairing is distinct?

Comment: Also, I see a START in that query, and the screenshot is of a very old browser version. You might want to work with a more modern example. The blog you are citing is from 2013, two minor versions back and using some different Cypher syntax. Nobody is using those older versions (at least I hope not).

Comment: @InverseFalcon Definitely not using that old version. The photo was just convenient because it clearly shows a "two nodes can have many relationships between them" situation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easier if you are using subqueries (Neo4j 4.1.x or higher). That's because the subquery can help scope the operations you need to perform (collect(), in this case) to expansions and work from a single country, per country, instead of having to perform it across all rows for the entirety of the query, which could stress the heap.

In reality, since the number of countries are low, it won't be a problem, but it's a good approach to use when dealing with larger sets of nodes.

```
MATCH (country:Country)
CALL {
 WITH country
 MATCH path = (country)<-[:FROM_AREA]-(:Artist)-[:RECORDING_CONTRACT]->(:Label)-[:FROM_AREA]->(other:Country)
 WHERE id(country) < id(other)
 RETURN other, collect(path)[0] as path
 LIMIT 20
}
RETURN country, path
LIMIT 20
```

Let's look at what this is doing.
We MATCH to :Country nodes.

Per country we will MATCH to the pattern you're looking for. If these are the only such paths and labels in the graph, then you can omit the labels in the pattern, as the relationship types should be enough to find the correct nodes.

The `WHERE id(country) < id(other)` is here to prevent mirrored results. For example, in the course of the query if we find a path from `(United Kingdom)-[*]-(United States)`, and we also find a path the other direction, for `(United States)-[*]-(United Kingdom)`, you probably don't want to return both. So we place a restriction on the graph ids so that only one of these will meet the restriction, and the mirrored result gets filtered out.

We use `RETURN other, collect(path)[0] as path` to get a single path per the country and other nodes. Remember that this is happening inside a subquery being called per country node, so even though `country` is not present here, this operation is being performed for a specific country node.

When we aggregate (such as with this `collect(path)`, the grouping key (usually the non-aggregation variables) become distinct, so for the country and the other country, this will collect all the paths between them and then take the first of that list of paths, so we get our single path between two distinct countries.

We LIMIT the subquery results to 20, since we know in total we don't want more than 20 paths, so per country we don't want more than 20 paths either. This might be a bit redundant for this case, but when the query is more complex it is the right approach to make sure you're not doing more work than is needed.

We also have another LIMIT outside the subquery, so that if there are only a few countries processed, with a few paths per country, the total paths won't exceed 20.

Comment: Excellent answer all around. Not only did it work exactly as I was hoping, but you broke down why it works and optimized the query. Thank you.